# Solving linear congruence classes

Tags: linear-algebra, congruences

Solve the following in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

> $[2][x] + [14][y] = [11] $
>
> $[8][x] +[7][y] =[12]$

solving for $x$ I got

> $[x] +[14][y]=[9]$ by multiplying the second equation by 2

So taking the difference of this with the first equation gives me

> $[x] = [2]$

solving for y I got

> $[8][x] + [11][y] = 14$ by multiplying the first equation by 4

This gives me

> $[4][y] = [2] \Rightarrow 4y \equiv 2 \pmod{15}$

By inspection, $y=8$ is a particular solution, so

> $[y]=[8]$

Is that all the solutions for $(x,y)$ I have to find?

I'm just a bit unsure about this because I know that these congruence class problems may have more solutions than normal.

Also it would be nice if someone has a tip or a trick for estimating how many solutions these problems can have

Comment: This is all good, nice work! The main thing to be wary of is division. You did it once, in solving $4y \equiv 2$. Because $4$ and $15$ are coprime this is ok. $4$ is invertible (in fact it is self-inverse, $4*4 \equiv 1$. You get multiple answers (or none at all) when you try to divide by values with a nontrivial gcd.

Comment: Wait, so what happens if the $a$ and $m$ in $a \equiv b \pmod m$ is not coprime?

Comment: Take a simple example. Say $3x \equiv 6$ (mod 15). The answer $x=2$ is apparent, but note that $3*5 \equiv 0$. We say that $3$ is a $0$-divisor (mod 15). So adding 5 to any solution won't change anything, and the solutions are $x=2, 7$ or $12$. If instead we tried $3x \equiv 7$ (mod 15) we would find no answers, as the only multiples of 3 are 0, 3, 6, 9 and 12. In general, for $ax \equiv b$ mod $n$, the number of solutions you will get is $0$ or $n$/(the number of distinct multiples of $a$)

Answer (score 1):

See, $[x]$ stands for a number of the form $x + 15k$, where $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $0 \leq x \leq 14$.

So the above equation can be rewritten as:
\begin{gather}
(2 + 15k_1)(x+15k_2) + (14+15k_3)(y + 15k_4) = 11 + 15k_5 \\
(8 + 15k_6)(x+15k_7) + (7+15k_8)(y + 15k_9) =12  + 15k_0
\end{gather}

Now, expand on both sides, and you can check that they simplify to:
\begin{gather}
2x + 14y = 11 + 15m \\
8x+7y=12 + 15n
\end{gather}

where $m,n$ are constants depending on the $k_i$, $0 \leq i \leq 9$.

Hence, solving this system of equations, we get:
$$
x=\frac{30n-15m+13}{14}, y = \frac{60m-15n+32}{49}
$$

Now, $x$ and $y$ are integers whenever $m,n$ exist such that the above equations are integrally satisfied.

Now, we twerk the equations slightly, to illustrate something:
\begin{gather}
15(2n-m) = 14x-13 \\
15(4m-n) =  49y-32
\end{gather}

Now, note that: exactly one value of $x$ between $0$ and $14$ is such that $14x-13$ is a multiple of $15$, namely $x=2$. Also there is only one value of $y$ between $0$ and $14$ such that $49y-32$ divides $15$, namely $y=8$.

Hence, we have to solve the equations 
\begin{gather}
2n-m = \frac{14*2-13}{15} =1 \\
4m-n = \frac{49*8-32}{15} = 24
\end{gather}

Solving, we see that $m=7,n=4$.

Hence, the only solution of this system is $x=2,y=8$.

In the end, you can see what it boiled down to:*the fact that $15 | 14x-13$ and $15 | 49x-32$ had unique solutions was the important point in the logic*. If they had more than one solution, then the solutions of the set of equations would not be unique.

Observe the procedure carefully: I took the equations, removed the congruences, added two constants $15m$ and $15n$ to each equation, solved it normally, and checked when the solutions are integers, that's all. It's very simple, and you can do it for other problems as well.

Comment: This is fine, but lacks elegance. We know $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can be expressed as the equivalence relation $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{nZ}$, but actually doing the math through the isomorphism is messy. Much better I think to use the ring in its native form - but then I'm an abstract algebraist...

Comment: @ScottBurns Your opinion makes sense. I feel that sometimes being a little elaborate makes the point clearer, in this case the expansion made it clear where the uniqueness was coming from, for example. I absolutely respect the fact that you are an abstract algebraist. I am in seventh standard, where the basics of algebra are taught, so I can't really say if I belong to any particular division, but this approach should work for people around my age.